# How to keep Elasticsearch synchronized with MySQL databse?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I stored data in `MySQL` as well as `Elasticsearch`.

When updating data in `MySQL`, I enqueue this data to `MQ` and let some consumer service update `Elasticsearch`.

If `MQ` is broken down，how to avoid producing dirty read?

Answer (score 0):

This should be covered by MQ. You can use a Queue to make sure that client will read that message only 1 time. After processing client should send back to the MQ "ACKNOWLEDGE" event (automatically or manually). Next the MQ is deleting that message from Queue.

In case you have multiple consumers (clients) listening the same Queue each client will lock several messages from the Queue and as a result each message will be processed only by a single consumer.